# Why the SMS code does not come during telephone authentication Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I took the code from the github to check if the phone authentication works. I am trying to send an SMS code to a Russian number, but it does not come. Firebase is exactly connected and SHA-1 too.
``

```
_verifyPhone() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: '+7${widget.phone}',
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance
              .signInWithCredential(credential)
              .then((value) async {
            if (value.user != null) {
              Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
                      (route) => false);
            }
          });
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
          print(e.message);
        },
        codeSent: (String verficationID, int resendToken) {
          setState(() {
            _verificationCode = verficationID;
          });
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationID) {
          setState(() {
            _verificationCode = verificationID;
          });
        },
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 30));
  }
```

``

Comment: what does the console print?

Comment: did you add push notification service into app?

Comment: in the console I saw that I needed to add the SHA-256 key in the firebase project. I added and it worked